# Ruby - Abbreviating a string containing a name to first name last initial

Tags: ruby

Fairly simple question I need to take a string containing, for example, "Bob Smith" and return "Bob S." - or "Javier de Luca" and return "Javier de L.". In other words, abbreviate the last word in a string to just the first initial and add a period.

Here's what I have - it works, but it seems clumsy.

```
str = str.split(' ')
str[str.length - 1] = "#{str.last[0]}."
str = str.join(' ')
```

Surely, there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>> "Bob Smith".sub(/(.+\b.).+\z/, '\1.')
=> "Bob S."
>> "Javier de Luca".sub(/(.+\b.).+\z/, '\1.')
=> "Javier de L."
```

This regular expression captures the entire string until the second character of the last word. It then replaces this string with the capture plus a period ala `\1.`

Comment: Beautiful. And I think I might even understand the regex. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
name = 'Javier de Luca'
name.sub!(/(\w)\w+$/, '\1.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tap` in 1.9:

```
str = str.split(/\s+/).tap { |a| a[-1].sub!(/(.).+/) { "#{$1}." } }.join(' ')
```

Using `a[-1].sub!` will modify the last element in-place so the `tap` block modifies `a` as well as passing it through to the `join` call. And, the `.+` takes care of leaving strange names like `Joe B` alone; if you want that to become `Joe B.` them use `.*` instead of `.+`.